# omnet++ on ubuntu 14.06 error in make file

Tags: linux, omnet++

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version running on VMWare Workstation 12 player and I am following https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf but it doesn't seem to find the make file, isn't the configure command supposed to dump the config in the makefile.ini, if so then make should work, when I get to make the file gives me an error. This is the code

```
ikhram@ubuntu:~$ cd omnetpp-5.3
ikhram@ubuntu:~/omnetpp-5.3$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for clang... no
checking for icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for clang++... no
checking for clang... no
checking for icpc... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether g++ supports -fno-stack-protector... yes
checking whether g++ supports -Wl,--no-as-needed... yes
checking whether g++ supports -Wl,--as-needed... yes
checking for swapcontext... yes
checking if shared libs need -fPIC... no
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... no
checking if --export-dynamic linker option is supported/needed... both
checking for flags needed to link with static libs containing simple modules... --whole-archive
configure: NOTE: Use the following syntax when linking with static libraries
configure: containing simple modules and other dynamically registered components:
configure:    g++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive <libs> -Wl,--no-whole-archive ...
checking whether linker supports -rpath... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking for make... make
checking for perl... perl
checking for swig... not found
checking for math with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... yes
checking for standard C++ lib with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-lstdc++"... yes
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... no
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-ldl"... yes
checking for qmake... /usr/bin/qmake
checking for moc... /usr/bin/moc
checking for uic... /usr/bin/uic
checking for rcc... /usr/bin/rcc
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL -L -Wl,-rpath="... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQtGui5 -lQtCore5 -lQtWidgets5 -lQtPrintSupport5 -lQtOpenGL5"... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport   -isystem  -isystem /QtCore -isystem /QtGui -isystem /QtWidgets -isystem /QtOpenGL -isystem /QtPrintSupport" LIBS=" -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework QtWidgets -framework QtPrintSupport -framework QtOpenGL"... no
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.
ikhram@ubuntu:~/omnetpp-5.3$ make
Makefile:54: Makefile.inc: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.inc'.  Stop.
ikhram@ubuntu:~/omnetpp-5.3$
```

Comment: »» configure: error: Cannot build ... «« : Means you will have to read the output from ./configure carefully, to see "missing" : clang, **qmake** ...

Answer (score 0):

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
[...]
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.
```

Try installing `qt5-qmake` and `qtbase5-dev` (the path says qt4, however later messages indicate "newer than Qt 5.4").

Answer (score 0):

> qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake'

The issue is "qtchooser". Even in Ubuntu 18.04, QT is set to **4** by default.

Solution : `export QT_SELECT=5`

---

Build example

```
sudo apt install g++ libxml2-dev libosgearth-dev bison flex clang swig libqt5opengl5-dev qt5-qmake openjdk-8-jre libopenmpi-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev

cd omnetpp-5.3/
export QT_SELECT=5
./configure WITH_OSGEARTH=no    // version 2.7 required 
export PATH=$HOME/omnetpp-5.3/bin:$PATH
           // my example: export PATH=/home/knudfl/omnetpp-5.3/bin:$PATH
make
```

---

EDIT : osgearth 2.7 for Ubuntu 16.04 → https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa → `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`